# Possible to configure SonarQube shortened url alias?

Tags: sonarqube

Currently our users have to enter http://biglongservername:9000/sonar in order to access our site.  Can it be configured to correspond to http://sonar?  Our DNS guys say that can't do any more than change the CNAME so that pinging "sonar" takes you to biglongservername.domainname.org, which doesn't help our users much, but might be a start.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 parts to this:

1. DNS configuration to alias http://biglongservername to http://sonar. Your DNS guys have already said they can make this happen for you, so take them up on it. The address becomes http://sonar:9000/sonar
2. Dropping the :9000 from the address. This is a matter of SonarQube configuration. In *$SONARQUBE_HOME/conf/sonar.properties*, set `sonar.web.port` to 80, the default port. Restart. The address becomes http://sonar/sonar
3. Dropping the "/sonar" from the end of the address. This is again a matter of configuration. In *$SONARQUBE_HOME/conf/sonar.properties* (yes, the same file) comment out `sonar.web.context`. Restart. The address becomes http://sonar.

Note that I would test each of these steps before moving on to the next one. And while step #1 can happen transparently to your users, they will certainly notice steps #2 and #3. You may want to set up a brief outage window.